# Path mapping with relative imports?

Tags: typescript

Currently [ReSpec](https://github.com/w3c/respec/) tries using `@ts-check` for JavaScript and has the following file tree:

```
root
|
|- js
|  |- deps // some external modules
|
|- src
   |- * // any files here will be compiled via babel and the output will be in js/*
```

Currently our file `src/core/foo.js` imports `js/deps/bar.js` by `import "../deps/bar"`. This works in runtime because the compilation output will be in `js/core/foo.js` but TypeScript language service warns that there is no `src/deps/bar.js`.

I want to do a kind of path-mapping but for relative imports like this, but AFAIK the path mapping feature in `jsconfig.json` only supports absolute paths (`import "deps/bar"`). (I prefer relative paths so that I can migrate to ES2015 module system without hassle.)

Is there a way to allow `import "../deps/bar"` inside `src/` so that TS language service would map it to `js/deps/*`?